# How to decode JSON in PHP and insert it into Mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm using the following code in PHP.

Its creating the file `post.json`, but inserting values into the table is not reflecting.

```
<?php
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
logToFile("post.json",$input);

$json_a = json_decode($input,true);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_table (Table_id, Menu_Item_Name, Menu_Item_Price, Menu_Item_quantity) VALUES('$json_a[TableId]','$json_a[ItemName]','$json_a[ItemPrice]','$json_a[ItemQuantity]')");


function logToFile($filename,$msg)
{
    $fd = fopen($filename,"a");
    $str="[".date("Y/m/d h:i:s")."]".$msg;
    fwrite($fd,$str."\n");
    fclose($fd);
}

?>
```

Comment: the $json_a array in the insert statement should be '${json_a['TableId']}'

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `'$json_a[foo]'` with `'" . $json_a['foo'] . "'` or `'${json_a['foo']}'`.

Comment: what error message do you get?Without knowing the error message it is hard to tell what can be the cause.